# Convert recorded audio file in to .wav format in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I want to record a audio file and upload to server in .wav format, but recorder doesn't allow to me to record a file into wav format.

for recording i have used the code :
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

Another way i have found, convert file from caff to wav after recording but this also not working for me.

I have used the code for convert file from caff to wav:

```
  -(BOOL)exportAssetAsWaveFormat:(NSURL*)filePath
    {
  NSError *error = nil ;

  NSDictionary *audioSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [ NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithBool:0], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                              [ NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                              [ NSData data], AVChannelLayoutKey, nil ];

//  NSString *audioFilePath = filePath;
AVURLAsset * URLAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]  initWithURL:recorder.url options:nil];

if (!URLAsset) return NO ;

AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:URLAsset error:&error];
if (error) return NO;

NSArray *tracks = [URLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
if (![tracks count]) return NO;

AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput *audioMixOutput = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput
                                               assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:tracks
                                               audioSettings :audioSetting];

if (![assetReader canAddOutput:audioMixOutput]) return NO ;

[assetReader addOutput :audioMixOutput];

if (![assetReader startReading]) return NO;



NSString *title = @"WavConverted";
NSArray *docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [docDirs objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *outPath = [[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent :title]
                     stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"wav" ];

NSURL *outURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outPath];
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:outURL
                                                      fileType:AVFileTypeWAVE
                                                         error:&error];
if (error) return NO;

AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [ AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType :AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                            outputSettings:audioSetting];
assetWriterInput. expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

if (![assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput]) return NO ;

[assetWriter addInput :assetWriterInput];

if (![assetWriter startWriting]) return NO;




[assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero ];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create( "assetWriterQueue", NULL );

[assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:queue usingBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"start");

    while (1)
    {
        if ([assetWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {

            CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [audioMixOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

            if (sampleBuffer) {
                [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer :sampleBuffer];
                CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
            } else {
                [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [assetWriter finishWriting];


    NSLog(@"finish %@",assetWriter);
}];
return YES;
//  dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why you need to convert directly record with wav file

Comment: you can record wav file

Comment: but how? i didn't found any way to record a wav file. can you help to me

Comment: I update my question, please check

Comment: [recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];

Comment: hmm now i can record .wav file, but still when i upload to server after converting data it shows .caff file.

Comment: So wav file recorder you are able to play. its a wav extension?

Comment: it creates error on server only.

Comment: if wav file is recorder successfully then You should start a new question for the upload file to the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54181/discussion-between-sunny-shah-and-prachi-rajput).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are uploading the file to a server, but I recommend you to not use the wav format because it's bigger in size than any other formats. Use caf, m4a, or any other formats instead.

You can record a wav file by setting `AVFormatIDKey` to `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`; no other encoding format will work.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: outPath];
NSError *err = nil;
audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                             settings: audioSetting 
                                                error:&err];

//prepare to record
[audioRecorder setDelegate:self];
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[audioRecorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)10000000000];
[audioRecorder record];
```

Comment: Yes it will work. but take care for the wav file AVFormatIDKey will be  kAudioFormatLinearPCM, no other encoding will work

Comment: dont forgot to add             [audioRecorder record];

Comment: Sunny Shah - you saved my day. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SunnyShah which `AVSampleRateKey` should I use to record a WAV file?

Comment: Excellent @SunnyShah  AVFormatIDKey will be kAudioFormatLinearPCM,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSString *wavFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleaudio" ofType:@"wav"];

NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wavFilePath];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

NSError *assetError = nil;
AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:songAsset
                                                           error:&assetError]
;
if (assetError) {
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}

AVAssetReaderOutput *assetReaderOutput = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput
                                          assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:songAsset.tracks
                                          audioSettings: nil];
if (! [assetReader canAddOutput: assetReaderOutput]) {
    NSLog (@"can't add reader output... die!");
    return;
}
[assetReader addOutput: assetReaderOutput];

NSString *strcafFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf",[wavFilePath stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
NSString *cafFilePath = [delegate.strCassettePathSide stringByAppendingPathComponent:strcafFileName];

NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cafFilePath];
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                      fileType:AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat
                                                         error:&assetError];
if (assetError)
{
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}

AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:11025], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                          outputSettings:outputSettings];
if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput])
{
    [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"can't add asset writer input... die!");
    return;
}

assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

[assetWriter startWriting];
[assetReader startReading];

AVAssetTrack *soundTrack = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake (0, soundTrack.naturalTimeScale);
[assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: startTime];

__block UInt64 convertedByteCount = 0;
dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);

[assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue
                                        usingBlock: ^
 {
     while (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
     {
         CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer = [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
         if (nextBuffer)
         {
             // append buffer
             [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer: nextBuffer];
             convertedByteCount += CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize (nextBuffer);

             CMSampleBufferInvalidate(nextBuffer);
             CFRelease(nextBuffer);
             nextBuffer = NULL;
         }
         else
         {
             [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
             //              [assetWriter finishWriting];
             [assetReader cancelReading];

             break;
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but, What is the difference here? i gave file URL whereas you have passed file path.

Comment: one more, what should be the file format before converting.

Comment: i get assetReader=nil;

Comment: error:
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo=0x1d1c5190 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c5893e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12847.)", NSURL=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/B5300A2B-1911-4D3F-ABF4-033D2128E9E3/Documents/

Comment: NSString *cafFilePath = [delegate.strCassettePathSide stringByAppendingPathComponent:strcafFileName];
, Could not understand this line?

Comment: use this link it will help u for all vise-versa conversion
http://code4app.net/ios/Sound-recorder-and-transormation-between-AMR-and-WAV/51565c3e6803fa5c76000005